# SQL Server stored procedure WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, where-clause

Need help with `WHERE` clause in this stored procedure.

How to write `WHERE` with this parameters and if any of these param contains specific value, then I need to get all values from that column ?

Sample if `@post1` contains 1 then select values from that columns that are equals to 1.
But if `@post1` contains 0 than select all values from that column. And that for all other parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStavke] 
    @dat1 date,
    @dat2 date,
    @god int, 
    @post1 int,
    @post2 int,
    @post3 int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
       [test1]
      ,[test2]
      ,[test3]
      ,[test3]
    FROM 
      [PN].[dbo].[Stavke] AS stavke
    LEFT JOIN 
      PN.dbo.Tip AS tip ON stavke.Vrsta = tip.id
    LEFT JOIN
      PN.dbo.Vrsta AS vrs ON stavke.Jedinica = vrs.id
END
```

Comment: How to find out which columns are selected?

Comment: Post1 =1 then select what columns????

Comment: No,  look now in this sp I need to write WHERE clause.. sample Where date1=@dat1 and date2=@dat2 and god=@god ....   and If all values exists in selected columns show it. But if any parameter contains 0 then in that case return all values . Sample if@dat1 contain 0 then  date1=@dat1 not to use.

Comment: ok, give more detail...  what columns would we look at if Post1 = 1?  do you mean that if Post1 = 1 then Test1 = 1 too?

Comment: Sample if @dat1 contain 0 then date1=@dat1 condition not need to use. May be I can get this bu providing null as parameter and if parameter is null not to use that condition ?

Comment: without knowing your table structure this is difficult.  your resonses don't jive with what you've shown.

Comment: T McKeown Thank you for your help. Here is one more sample maybe this is better explained:    select c1,c2,c3,c4 
from db

where c1=@c1 and c2=@c2 and c3=@c3

So, if all parameters exists in these colums I wil get one row result.

But if value of one of parameters does not exists in columns then that condition dont use.
sample @c1 =0 and this value not exists so c1=@c1 condition I dont need it in where clause. 
Or this condition I need to exclude.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
      [test1]
     ,[test2]
     ,[test3]
     ,[test3]

FROM [PN].[dbo].[Stavke] as  stavke
left join PN.dbo.Tip  as tip on  stavke.Vrsta=tip.id
left join PN.dbo.Vrsta  as vrs on  stavke.Jedinica = vrs.id
WHERE (@Post1 = 0 OR (@Post1 = 1 AND 1 IN( TEST1,TEST2,TEST3))
 AND (@Post2 = 0 OR (@Post2 = 1 AND 1 IN( TEST1,TEST2,TEST3))
```